# I can't read data with openpyxl, but I can read after saving the target file manually

Tags: python, excel, xlsx, openpyxl

I have encountered a strange phenomenon on openpyxl.

Does anyone know how to solve it?

---

(1)
I want to manipulate xlsx files downloaded from outside website (like banking transactions and here offers it in xlsx format).

Then I want to extract data with openpyxl.

(2)
This is my code.

```
wb = xl.load_workbook(file, data_only=True, read_only=True)
ws = wb[sh]
print( ws.cell(column=col, row=row).value )
```

(3)
I run this code.
Then the result is "None".

(4)
I open the file and confirm there are data.

(5)
I save the file (without any change).

(6)
I run the code again.
Then the result is not "None", but data which is stored in xlsx.

---

It is fine, but I think it is quite dull to open and save once every time for this operation.

I read that options like 'data_only', 'use_iterators', 'read_only' might change the returned values. I tried commenting out some of them and see if the result changes, but it is not the cause.

Does anyone know about a solution?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking at files created by another library that, like openpyxl, does not evaluate formulae. In this case, you must open the file in application like Excel or OpenOffice so that the formulae can be evaluated and the results stored as a cache.

Comment: I see. If so, my process above is the right one. I'll think another method. Though thank you very much for your coment.